# Integral of a k-form

Tags: differential-forms

Just got to the culminating chapter in Munkres’s *Analysis on Manifolds* and I’ve been thrown for a loop.

The author is in the process of defining the integral of a k-form η on A, an open set of R$^k$. We know that η can be written uniquely in the form η = f dx$_1$ $\land$ ··· $\land$ dx$_k$ , where $\land$ is the wedge product, f: R$^k$ --> R, and dx$_i$  equals the elementary 1-form in R$^k$.

Munkres defines the integral as follows:

$\int_A η$ = $\int_A f$.

But I don’t understand what motivates this definition.

What throws me is that η(x) = f(x) · (dx$_1$ $\land$ ··· $\land$ dx$_k$)(x) where x is in A, and (dx$_1$ $\land$ ··· $\land$ dx$_k$)(x) is an alternating k-tensor in { (x;v) | v an element of R$^k$ }.

Supposing just for the sake of argument that f = 1, shouldn't

$\int_A η$ = $\int_A (dx_1 \land ··· \land dx_k)$?

In which case, what the heck is

$\int_A (dx_1 \land ··· \land dx_k)$?

For x an element of A, (dx$_1$ $\land$ ··· $\land$ dx$_k$)(x) is simply the name of a function -- in this case an alternating k-tensor. This alternating k-tensor has no arguments and thus no value that can be summed ( = integrated).

I know I must have missed something fundamental. Can you please help me understand where I went wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't have Munkrese here, but, first, $A$ should be bounded or $f$ must meet a suitable asymptotic condition for the integral to be finite. Second, the integral of a $k$-form is really fairly simple, you just drop the wedges and do a suitable $k$-fold integral on the appropriate parameter domain. Perhaps that is what is meant by $\int_A f$. Is that his notation for an ordinary multivariate integral. Note, a big distinction is that the form integral is oriented whereas the multivariate one is not. The orientation is implicit within the pull-back procedure which requires a choice of $k$-form.

Comment: Thanks for your response, James. What's the rationale for "dropping the wedges," as you say? Isn't that kind of like saying "We can't evaluate the integral of f · g (on the open set A), but we can evaluate the integral of f alone, so let's just drop g"?